# Check whether a user is in a Discord Server (Supabase)

Tags: reactjs, discord.js, supabase

I want to check whether a user is a member of our discord server.
I'm using Supabase project and React.js for frontend.
How to make "Join our server" button?
And how should I check server members?

```
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnnonKey)
  
async function signInWithDiscord() {
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: 'discord',
  })
  console.log(data, error)
}
```

The above function is being used for signing in with discord.